# How to do auto tooltip validation msg without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here I created sample file for validation, which is working fine...
I need to achieve same thing without using jquery..
My requirement is Error message need to show in auto tooltip. It needs to be shown automatically when there is error and hide automatically once error cleared. Until error clear popup need to be stay.

is it possible to achieve same thing without jquery???

```js
function validate(el) {
  var regex = /^\d+$/g;
  var valid = regex.test(el.value);
  if (!valid) {
    
    // Check if popover is already visible to handle flicker effect.
    if ($("#txtInput").next('div.popover').length == 0) {
      
      $('#txtInput').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        content: 'This is not a valid entry'
      }).popover('show');
      
    }
  } else {
    $('#txtInput').popover('hide');
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Enter value:
<input type="text" id="txtInput" onkeyup="validate(this)">
```

Comment: Take a look at both ui-validate as well as ui-bootstrap. ui-bootstrap has a built in tooltip option and validation can be built into this.

Comment: You could use `ui-bootstrap` module which has `popover` directive http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

Comment: @miniclip take a look at the link which I;ve provided in comment

Comment: yeah I seen just now... How can i create one form while click submit...all error msg need to popover..

Comment: for validation propose only i need this..' is there any sample form?

Answer (score 0):

use this
.`

```
<!-- show an error if username is too short -->
<p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength">Username is too short.</p>

<!-- show an error if username is too long -->
<p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength">Username is too long.</p>

<!-- show an error if this isn't filled in -->
<p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.required">Your username is required.</p>
```

`

or use this by ngMessages

```
<form name="userForm">

<input 
    type="text" 
    name="username" 
    ng-model="user.username" 
    ng-minlength="3" 
    ng-maxlength="8"
    required>

<div ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
    <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
    <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can u add as runable example?

Comment: reffer  this https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages